# Suppressing Model-Dialog when running PyQGIS Script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I wrote a tiny script that has a fixed input and fixed output, i.e. I don't need any user interaction.
However, when running my script the Model-dialog

[image]

pops up although the script already ran. Is it possible to suppress the dialog?

I am on QGIS 3.8.3.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.